# JSF 2 : Is this a good approach to handle Business exceptions?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Following my previous question in [Creating FacesMessage in action method outside JSF conversion/validation mechanism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193784/creating-faces-message-from-outside-jsf-conversion-validation-mechanism) , i'm trying to handle the exceptions thrown from the business layer outside my managed beans.

The strategy is to search and convert business exceptions to faces messages in the a PhaseListener,.

It is working as i expected, but im just wondering if im just reinventing the wheel, or doing it right with the wrong way ?

Here's my code sample snippet :

```
public class BusinessExceptionHandler implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent phaseEvent) {
        ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler = phaseEvent.getFacesContext().getExceptionHandler();

        // just debugging the handled exception, nothing here
        /*
        for (ExceptionQueuedEvent event : exceptionHandler.getHandledExceptionQueuedEvents()) {
            ExceptionQueuedEventContext context = (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) event.getSource();
            System.out.println("handled exception : " + context.getException());
        }*/

        for (Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> it = exceptionHandler.getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator(); 
                it.hasNext();) {

            ExceptionQueuedEvent event = it.next();
            ExceptionQueuedEventContext eventContext = (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) event.getSource();
            Throwable e = eventContext.getException();
            System.out.println("unhandled exception : " + e);

            // get the root cause exception
            while (e.getCause() != null) { 
                e = e.getCause();
            }

            System.out.println("cause exception : " + e + 
                ", cause exception is BE : " + (e instanceof BusinessException));

            // handle BE
            if (e instanceof BusinessException) {
                BusinessException be = (BusinessException) e;
                System.out.println("processing BE " + be);
                FacesMessage message = Messages.getMessage(
                    "com.corejsf.errors", 
                    be.getMessage(), 
                    be.getParamValues()
                );
                FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                context.addMessage(null, message);
                it.remove(); // remove the exception

                // works fine without this block, if BE is thrown, always return to the original page
                /*
                NavigationHandler navigationHandler = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
                System.out.println("navigating to " + context.getViewRoot().getViewId());
                navigationHandler.handleNavigation(context, context.getViewRoot().getViewId(), null);
                */
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent phaseEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION;
    }

}
```

Thank you !

Regards,
Albert Kam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is an intermix of JSF 1.x and JSF 2.x exception handling approaches. Since you're using JSF 2.x, I'd suggest a pure JSF 2.x approach without a `PhaseListener` and with help of the new [`ExceptionHandler` API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExceptionHandler.html).

You can find an example which treats the `ViewExpiredException` in page 282 of the book *"JSF 2.0: The Complete Reference"* which is online available [here](http://www.google.com/search?tbs=bks%3A1&tbo=1&q=jsf+%22the+complete+reference%22+%22a+custom+exceptionhandler+example%22&btnG=Search+Books) (click the 1st result link).

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for the idea. The page 282 is not available. But after some googling, i found edburn's article about this kind of matter, and will use this practice later : http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2009/09/03/dealing-gracefully-viewexpiredexception-jsf2

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you're going this route, creating and registering your own exception handler is really easy.  Though easier will be Seam Catch ( http://seamframework.org/Seam3/CatchModule and http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/catch/3.0.0.Alpha1/reference/en-US/html_single/ ).  I don't have a JSF bridge just yet, but it will be very easy to do.  Then all you have to do is write one method that will handle a specific exception, and you'll be done!

Comment: Im still new to the jsf and full of doubts about the best practices, hence the question above :) Thanks for the suggestion, though im not using seam framework, im gonna take a look about the exception handler api.