# How to pass error message to the error page via ExceptionHandler?

Tags: jsf-2, exception, deltaspike

My debut J2EE 6 app. 
I am using a solder ExceptionHandler to deal with exceptions, but I'm not liking it much. It seems way too complicated for what I want to do.

For example

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.jboss.solder.exception.control.CaughtException;
import org.jboss.solder.exception.control.Handles;
import org.jboss.solder.exception.control.HandlesExceptions;

/**
 * Handle exceptions and redirect page.
 */
@HandlesExceptions
public class ExceptionHandlers {


    void noResult(
            @Handles CaughtException<dne.nmst.ond.exceptions.OfficeNotFoundException> caught,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        caught.handled();

        try {
            String msg = caught.getException().getMessage();
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()
                    + "/searchOffice.xhtml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I would like to display the error message from OfficeNotFoundException in searchOffice.xhtml.  How do I get it from here to there?

One thing I considered was putting the error into the flash context, but I get NPE when trying to reference FacesContext from this exception handling class.

I tried an error-page entry in web.xml.  I could not get it to work.

I know I could pass it as a request parameter in the redirect, but that seems like a workaround. I want to do it the simplest and "most correct" way (whatever that means).

I miss Seam 2 where we could just do this in pages.xml:

```
<exception class="dne.nmst.ond.exceptions.OfficeNotFoundException">
  <redirect include-page-params="false" view-id="searchOffice.xhtml">
  <message severity="warn"/>
</redirect>
```

with

```
<h:messages />
```

in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the error message in your code and specify which h:messages tag the message should appear in. Refer the answer below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4194098/2450373