# Display a validation message on an h:outputText

Tags: ajax, jsf

So I have this form on my login.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="login">
    <p:graphicImage url="img/logo.jpg" width="448" height="119"/>
    <p> Si pertenece a una empresa, inserte su usuario y password. </p>
    <p:outputLabel for="usuario" value="Usuario:" />
    <p:inputText id="usuario" value="#{loginController.login.username}"/>
    <p:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
    <p:password id="password" value="#{loginController.login.password}"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Login" update="out" actionListener="#{loginController.login()}"/>
    <h:outputText id="out" />
    <a href="#"> Si no pertenece a una empresa, haga click para continuar</a>
</h:form>
```

When the button is clicked, this method is activated:

```
public String login() {
    login = service.login(login.getUsername(), login.getPassword());

    if (login.getUsername() == null) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Usuario y/o password incorrecto!"));
        return null;
    } else {
        return "index.jsf?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

I am trying to validate if the user exists or not but using AJAX. So if the username and password are incorrect, I want it to display the message on the `<h:outputText>` without reloading the page. If it is successful, I want the redirect to happen. None of these are working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Display that message using an `<h:messages globalOnly="true" .../>`. `globalOnly` is set to `true` because you need not display the message for a specific component i.e. you do not associate the given `<h:messages>` with a specific component in this example - you have set a `null` client id here `.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Usuario y/o password incorrecto!"))`.

Comment: @Tiny: My understanding from the op was that he does not want it globally but 'on' the `h:outputText`

Comment: Maybe requirement-dependent (an `<h:message>` component may also be chosen). @Kukeltje

Comment: `h:outputText` component is not designed for this requirement. As @Tiny says, use the `h:message`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h:outputText>` isn't designed for the purpose of displaying faces messages. You could hack around as below

```
<h:outputText value="#{facesContext.messageList[0].summary}" />
```

but this is plain ugly. You're supposed to use `<h:message>` or `<h:messages>` to show faces messages (or the PrimeFaces `<p:xxx>` equivalents, of course).

With `addMessage(null, message)` you're with the `null` client ID basically adding a *global* message. You can show them exclusively as below:

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```

You can also add a message for a specific component like so
`addMessage("login", message)`, referencing the `<h:form id="login">`.

```
context.addMessage("login", new FacesMessage("Unknown login. Perhaps you want to sign up?"));
```

You can the display it with a `<h:message>` whose `for` attribute references exactly that ID:

```
<h:message for="login" />
```

Of course, give it an `id` and refer it in `<p:commandButton update>`.

```
<p:commandButton ... update="loginMessage" />
...
<h:message id="loginMessage" for="login" />
```

The `<p:xxx>` equivalents have by the way an `autoUpdate="true"` attribute which removes the need to do so.

#### See also:

- [Creating FacesMessage in action method outside JSF conversion/validation mechanism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193784/creating-faces-message-from-outside-jsf-conversion-validation-mechanism/)

---

As to the redirect fail, it's caused by the PrimeFaces showcase examples being littered with `actionListener` instead of `action` on `<p:commandButton>` over all place, and therefore confusing starters who actually intend to invoke business actions and navigation using `<p:commandButton>`.

You should be using `action` attribute instead.

```
<p:commandButton ... action="#{loginController.login}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/)

Comment: Thank you. It was really helpful but I have another question. If I wanted my login() method above not to return a String but to be void. What can I do instead of return "index.jsf?faces-redirect=true"? Since I want to make it void, I can't return something.

Comment: Use `ExternalContext#redirect()`. There are examples in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-navigation-forward-and-when-to-use-w/11277482#11277482

Comment: By the way, your profile mentions "J2EE", but this was succeeded by "Java EE" nearly a decade ago. Surely you're not working with old technology?

Comment: thank you for that comment. I recently started developing Java enterprise applications. I use modern tools like JSF 2.0, Java 8, Hibernate and SOAP web service. I guess I never understood the different between Java EE and J2EE. Now I know the difference.

Comment: So when you see "J2EE" vacancies while searching for a job, by all means skip them. Generally either the HR/Team has no idea what it's talking about, or you had to maintain a legacy J2EE monster app ;)

Answer (score 0):

On command button you are using actionListener to navigate while actionListener is used for the method which return void. If you have to navigate use "action" attribute of "h:commandButton" rather than "actionListener".

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am actually about to start studying to understand the differences between action and actionListener.@BalusC has a really good post explaining it

Comment: One more point is there that In a command button when you define both action and actionListener than first actionListener will get called and after that action will get called.